# Как заставит "бота" принимать (понимать) русский текст

Tags: python, discord, бот

Как мне заставить моего бота понимать русский язык..
К примеру сейчас вот кусок кода, если ему написать hello, он ответит, если я вместо hello заменю на Привет, и напишу в чате привет, молчит как партизан

```
    if message.content.lower() == 'hello':
        parts = message.content.split(' ')
        await message.channel.send('Привет. Меня зовут ping, я 
        местный робот. Введи команду !ping и 
        мы посмотрим, что можно сделать!')
        return
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как он должен догадаться, что привет это то же самое что hello? Добавьте в условие `or  message.content.lower == 'Привет'

Comment: Так вместо hello привет в коде пишу. Добавил or message.content.lower == 'Привет', не помогло, молчит партизан

Comment: or message.content.lower() == 'Привет'  скобки забыл указать )) работает)

Comment: if message.content.lower() in ['hello', 'привет']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю это должно помочь:
Замените

```py
    if message.content.lower() == 'hello':
        parts = message.content.split(' ')
        await message.channel.send('Привет. Меня зовут ping, я 
        местный робот. Введи команду !ping и 
        мы посмотрим, что можно сделать!')
        return
```

На это:

```py
    if message.content.lower() == 'hello' or message.content.lower() == 'Привет':
        parts = message.content.split(' ')
        await message.channel.send('Привет. Меня зовут ping, я 
        местный робот. Введи команду !ping и 
        мы посмотрим, что можно сделать!')
        return
```

Или как написал один из комментаторов:

```py
if message.content.lower() in ["hello", "Привет"]:
    ...
```